# Mysqli_error() and logic issues in pagination

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

**Problem**

First time working with pagination so I'm still trying to understand how this all fits together. I'm fairly confident that the method I have researched and applied here will work however I am encountering a strange error.

The data is not being accessed due to a failure of the second mysqli_query which incurs the error message `Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given`.

There is only one entry in the database and I can only assume that this must be resulting in some strange logic but I'm not even 100% that it makes sense for that to be happening. It is also definitely the second mysqli_query as `Could not get that data` is the output.

Would really appreciate some explanation of the process of pagination and if anyone can spot my mistake that would be greatly appreciated.

**Code**

```
<?php 

        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        if (!$connect) {die(mysql_error());}mysqli_select_db($connect, "story.time");

         $rec_limit = 5;
         $sql = "SELECT count(id) FROM toptable ";
         $retval = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

         if(! $retval ){die('Could not get this data: ' . mysql_error());}
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
         $rec_count = $row[0];

         if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) ){$page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;$offset = $rec_limit * $page;}
         else{$page = 0;$offset = 0;}
         $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);
         $sql = "SELECT id, name, content FROM toptable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

         $retval = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
         if(! $retval ){die('Could not get that data: ' . mysqli_error($retval));}

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
         {echo "{$row['id']}  <br> "."{$row['name']} <br> "."{$row['content']} <br> ";}

         if( $page > 0 ){$last = $page - 2;
            echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
            echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";}

         else if( $page == 0 )
         {echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";}

         else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
         {$last = $page - 2;echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a>";}

         mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

Comment: I like your willpower, but why not use a class or script that already has all these elements by default? Do you need a wheel that has never been invented before?

Comment: @davejal It's more of a exercise in learning but I'd be happy to employ a different method if it helped. Would you recommend anything?

Comment: If it's an exercise continue (best way to learn). There are plenty I can't really suggest any, but I have been using a [framework](http://laravel.com/) for some time now. This also teaches you to write OOP programs, instead of procedural.

Comment: And while you're at it check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/3664960) to debug your php code.

Comment: @davejal Well that was pretty much why I came here because otherwise I'll be stuck doing it myself forever. This looks really nice and I'll investigate it more another time, thanks.

Comment: SO is not here to suggest any tutorial/framework or tool, so sorry, I can't really suggest anything. But to help further with this error, could you add the line which produces the first error?

Comment: @davejal No worries. So the error occurs during this section `$sql = "SELECT id, name, content FROM toptable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

         $retval = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
         if(! $retval ){die('Could not get that data: ' . mysqli_error($retval));}`

Comment: @davejal I should also say, I've tried removed $offset and $rec_limit and the outcome is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98044/discussion-between-davejal-and-masteryupa).

Comment: added some comments in chat... check it out

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$connect) {die(mysql_error());}mysqli_select_db($connect, "story.time");
```

**mysql_error()**

you're using mysql**i** elsewhere. Try to stick to one.